# Are all Hausdorff extremally disconnected P-spaces also regular?

Tags: general-topology

A space is extremally disconnected if closure of any open set is open. It's a P-space when intersection of any countable amount of open sets is open.

There exist Hausdorff extremally disconnected spaces that are not regular e.g. strong ultrafilter topology (this is not a P-space since if $\mathcal{U}$ is a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, then there exist $A_i\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\bigcap_i A_i = \emptyset$, so that $\bigcap_i (A_i\cup \{\mathcal{U}\}) = \{\mathcal{U}\}$ is not open).

Are all Hausdorff
extremally
disconnected P-spaces also regular?